# Query run as stored procedure (sp_sqlexec) delivers no results (T-SQL, SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to run a query that shows me all columns from all tables in a database with the datatype `varchar` and a maximum length of 8000 characters.

This is my code so far.

```
DECLARE @tabs VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @tabs = 
(
  SELECT STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ',' + [TABLE_NAME]
                 FROM [DB-Test].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                 WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR' AND
                       CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 8000
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
);

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cols = 
(
  SELECT STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ',' + [TABLE_NAME] + '.' + [COLUMN_NAME]
                 FROM [DB-Test].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                 WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR' AND
                       CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 8000
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
);

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM ' + @tabs

EXEC sp_sqlexec @query
```

When I run the query I get all the column names, but not the values in the columns. It's empty. No 'NULL'-values. As if @cols is interpreted as simple string maybe.
Why?

(When I read out @cols and @tabs they are correct.)

Comment: Start by printing out `@query`.  The answer will probably be obvious.

Comment: I did. The query is correct. Also there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is one table available in your database which have column with VARCHAR datatype and 8000 length but that table don't have any records. Try by including only those column and table which have at least one record available.

You can try below. Check it and let me know if it works.

```
DECLARE @tabs VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

; WITH CTE AS 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT TA.NAME TABLENAME
      , SUM(PA.ROWS) OVER (PARTITION BY TA.NAME ) NOOFROW
 FROM SYS.TABLES TA
 INNER JOIN SYS.PARTITIONS PA ON PA.OBJECT_ID = TA.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS SC ON TA.SCHEMA_ID = SC.SCHEMA_ID
 WHERE TA.IS_MS_SHIPPED = 0 AND PA.INDEX_ID IN (1,0) 
), TABLENAME AS
(
    SELECT ITBL.[TABLE_NAME]
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ITBL
    WHERE ITBL.DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR' AND
          ITBL.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 8000  
          AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE CTE.TABLENAME = ITBL.TABLE_NAME AND CTE.NOOFROW > 0) -- To check no of record available in table
)
SELECT @tabs = @tabs+ISNULL(','+TABLE_NAME, '')
FROM TABLENAME

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

; WITH CTE AS 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT TA.NAME TABLENAME
      , SUM(PA.ROWS) OVER (PARTITION BY TA.NAME ) NOOFROW
 FROM SYS.TABLES TA
 INNER JOIN SYS.PARTITIONS PA ON PA.OBJECT_ID = TA.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS SC ON TA.SCHEMA_ID = SC.SCHEMA_ID
 WHERE TA.IS_MS_SHIPPED = 0 AND PA.INDEX_ID IN (1,0) 
), TABLENAME AS
(
    SELECT ITBL.[TABLE_NAME], ITBL.[COLUMN_NAME]
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ITBL
    WHERE ITBL.DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR' AND
          ITBL.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 8000  
          AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE CTE.TABLENAME = ITBL.TABLE_NAME AND CTE.NOOFROW > 0) -- To check no of record available in table
)
SELECT @cols = @cols+ISNULL(','+[TABLE_NAME]+'.'+[COLUMN_NAME], '')
FROM TABLENAME

IF LEN(@cols) > 0 AND LEN(@tabs) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + STUFF(@cols,1,1,'') + ' FROM ' + STUFF(@tabs,1,1, '')

    EXEC sp_sqlexec @query  
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No Column available with data where it''s datatype is VARCHAR and length is 8000'
END
```